# In a set $\mathbb{A} = (0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ there is a defined binary operation $*$ such that $a * b = \mathrm{\mathit{a}}^{log_5 b}$ . Prove closure.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $a$ and $b$ belong to $\mathbb{A}$. This seems so intuitive and simple to prove, but I simply do not know where should I start from. I just got into college and I am new to abstract algebra. Any indication is appreciated.
My current progress with the problem:
We know from the given the set that its members must be greater than $0$ and can not be equal to $1$. So, we have to prove that $\mathrm{\mathit{a}}^{log_5 b}$ is greater than $0$ and not equal to $1$. The latter is easy to prove, as real number represented as $\mathrm{x}^y$, where $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, is equal to $1$ if $y = 0$ or $x = 1$ . Since we know that $a\neq 1$ as it belongs to $\mathbb{A}$, and since we know that $log_5b\neq 0$ because $b$ also belongs to $\mathbb{A}$ and as such can not be equal to $1$, it is proven that $\mathrm{\mathit{a}}^{log_5 b}\neq 1$. For the former, since we know that $a$ is greater than zero, $a$ raised to any exponent $log_5 b$ where $b$ belongs to $\mathbb{A}$ and is in accordance with logarithm rules, is guaranteed to be positive, but I feel that that proof is either incomplete or illogical.

Comment: I would not call that set $\mathbb{C}$, since that symbol is pretty typically reserved for the complex numbers.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the down/close votes.  OP has given their understanding of the problem and has supplied a pretty-close solution, one that can actually be critiqued.

Comment: i called it $\mathbb{C}$ because thats how it was called in the original problem. I will rename it to some other letter now so that it doesnt get confused for complex numbers.